# How to formula if with multi conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying formula `if` with multi conditions in Excel.

but the result `#VALUE!`is there is something wrong with my formula please guide me

Thanks

| DATE | IN/OUT | TIME | DEF IN | DEF OUT | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13-03-24 | IN | 7:35:41 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 |  |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 15:42:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 |  |
| 13-03-24 | IN | 8:35:41 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 |  |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 15:42:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 |  |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 13:00:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 |  |
|  | IN |  |  |  |  |

```
=IF(A2="",""),IF(AND(B2="OUT",E2<=C2),"NORMAL","LATE"),IF(AND(B2="IN",D2<=C2),"NORMAL","LATE")
```

Result from above formula

| DATE | IN/OUT | TIME | DEF IN | DEF OUT | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13-03-24 | IN | 7:35:41 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | #VALUE! |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 15:42:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | #VALUE! |
| 13-03-24 | IN | 8:35:41 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | #VALUE! |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 15:42:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | #VALUE! |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 13:00:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | #VALUE! |
|  | IN |  |  |  | #VALUE! |

[image]

Desired Result

| DATE | IN/OUT | TIME | DEF IN | DEF OUT | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13-03-24 | IN | 7:35:41 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | NORMAL |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 15:42:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | NORMAL |
| 13-03-24 | IN | 8:35:41 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | LATE |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 15:42:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | NORMAL |
| 13-03-24 | OUT | 13:00:10 | 8:00:00 | 15:30:00 | LATE |
|  | IN |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Yeah, far too many parentheses happening there.

Comment: can you further explain the logic behind your desired output?

Comment: You close the first if to early : IF(A2="","") so you need to test each bit - Excel does show you which arguement you are editing so you should see where it stops.

Comment: @MrIrrelevant , Example : if status `IN` and time `8:35:41` is bigger than `DEF IN : 8:00:00` so result `LATE`

Comment: Improve your question with relevant info, don't leave it in comments.

Comment: What's the sense of this part in the beginning? `A2="",""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works ...

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(AND(B2="IN",C2<=D2),"NORMAL",IF(AND(B2="OUT",E2<=C2),"NORMAL","LATE")))
```

... or this ...

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(OR(AND(B2="IN",C2<=D2),AND(B2="OUT",E2<=C2)),"NORMAL","LATE"))
```